# Will performance be obviously negatively impacted If most functions are expanded (e.g. inlined)?

Tags: c, performance

One purpose of function is code reuse. Another possible usage is saving program memory, which also means performance considering I-cache and L2+ cache occupation and main memory bandwidth occupied by instruction fetching.

For curiosity, the question is will the performance of daily software (like a whole OS plus a lot of applications, not just some small benchmarking code) be indeed obviously impacted if all functions of are "expanded"? It is mainly about the impact on cache and main memory instruction bandwidth.

**The reason that the impact may be not obvious** is that for that much of instructions, it doesn't matter they are copied a lot of times or reused. Also the fact may be that the locality mainly come from loop instead of function calls.

"expand" means whenever a function is called, the whole function is put in place, or equivalently a new copy of the function is created (statically by the "function expanding tool" for normal calls, or dynamically by some "function expanding runtime" for funtion pointer calls) and called there.

"expand" is hard to define for all advanced lanuguage syntax situations (such as lambda/closure etc) and the imagined tool that "expand" source code will be complex. Let's suppose for now only function calls that are simple to expand are expanded and it can even be supposes that all code are written in C. And obviously recursive calls can't be expanded and not fall into a discussion about how program can be expanded which is not the point of the question.

Lets also suppose the computer have enough main memory, since the expanded image of OS plus application could be quite large, like 1TB?

Comment: Compilers are *very* good at optimizing, so you generally don't need to worry about it.  As a rule, only optimize what has been measured to be a bottleneck.

Comment: Performance is not just related to main memory, you need to consider the cache hit/miss as well.

Comment: @dbush The point is not to optimize please check the content.

Comment: Any decent compiler will ignore the inline directive if it's not appropriate to use for the specified code, which makes this a moot question. You're trying to outguess the compiler and its optimizations, which most of the time is an absolute waste of time - the compiler is almost always smarter than the developer using it.

Comment: @KenWhite That not the point of the question, I really need to edit it.

Comment: The image size is irrelevant. OSes don't load the entire image into memory at one time. It is paged in and out as needed during execution Your question about the effect on performance probably isn't relevant either; as I said, most decent compilers won't inline code where it isn't appropriate to do so.

Comment: You say "locality mainly come from loop instead of function calls" without supporting evidence. There are a *lot* of functions in certain categories that are called a *lot* from all over a typical program, often with a *lot* of code that would expand if you forced complete inlining. Think memory allocation, string manipulation and I/O routines, that sort of thing. I/O in particular involves a *ton* of code; if it's all inlined, you're eventually going to have problems where loading more code from the executable becomes a bottleneck because you inlined *all* of `<iostream>` a few hundred times.

Comment: And remember, those loops that provide all that locality? If you expanded all the functions called in the loop in their entirety, that loop, from top to bottom, may be large enough to spill from cache; by the time you reach the bottom and loop back to the top, you've gotta load the top of the loop's code again, thanks to over-inlining. The point is, a little excess inlining won't hurt. But taken to *massive* excess, you go from merely having inefficient use of the CPU's L1/L2/L3 caches, to needing to read from the disk live (orders of magnitude slower than RAM even for SSDs).

Comment: There is no single/general answer to this. Optimization depends on hardware and circumstances, and getting peak performance may require studying the circumstances and their interactions with hardware carefully. Inlining functions can improve performance by reducing branches and allowing optimizations between the inlined functions and surrounding code. Inlining functions can degrade performance by pushing code size out of the L1 cache. In some cases, this can cause thrashing which degrades performance greatly.

Comment: @ShadowRanger "If you expanded all the functions called in the loop in their entirety, that loop, from top to bottom, may be large enough to spill from cache" Thas't a good idea, some possible bug for the idea: if a loop call a lot of non-inlined functions, the loop may be not important anymore?

Comment: @ShadowRanger "There are a lot of functions in certain categories that are called a lot..." But the key is, will that "a lot of" really have major relation ship will cache?

Answer (score 1):

Compilers are very efficient nowadays, and a simple kind of "expansion" will always be done by the compiler, also the extend of "expansion" will increase if the build does not use optimization for smaller file size.

From my extensive experience optimizing C codes, I do not think it will be a noticeable difference if use in OS for example, but it is very useful in (for example) image processing.

This could be done manually in C using Macros instead of functions, which will expand functions (in this case Macros) during pre-processing which will result in faster code execution.

**EDIT:**

It could affect the performance negatively as mentioned here:

1. [Linux kernel coding style documentation](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.38/Documentation/CodingStyle#L692)
2. [inline function
   C++](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions#inline-and-perf)

**BUT** still I don't think in a real scenario it will hurt that much unless the system memory is so little that the increase in executable files size would be enough to overwhelm the memory.

Comment: The OP is asking about an intentional *always*-expand behavior in the compiler, not just a "inline when beneficial" behavior and asking what the effect would be. Literally inlining everything, including I/O routines and memory allocation routines at every point of use. This doesn't really address that question, it just says "inlining is already done, and it's usually helpful".

Comment: @ShadowRanger I've edited my answer to address the issue directly.

Comment: The last paragraph is incorrect. Inlining functions can have negative effects on performance. The statement “it will never make it worse” is false.

Comment: @EricPostpischil actually I think you are correct and I've edited my answer. but still I don't think this will happen in  a real life scenario

Comment: It's not the size of system RAM that's important here, but the size of the L1 instruction cache. A little too much inlining can *easily* make the program's critical path not fit in L1, and thus slow it down to the speed of L2, or worse if the replacement logic starts [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)).